# Remmert, exercise 5, chapter 7 section 3. Theory of Complex Functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be holomorphic on a domain $D$, and let $r>0$, $\bar B(0,r)\subseteq D$. Suppose that $a$, $|a|=r$ is such that $g(a)=0,g'(a)\neq 0$, $f(a)\neq 0$ and that $g$ doesn't vanish in $\bar B(0,r)\setminus \{a\}$. If $\sum a_n z^n$ is the powerseries of $f/g$ around $0$, I have to show that $a_n/a_{n+1}\to a$. The books says "Use the geometric series". I honestly couldn't get anything out of it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Around $a$ the function $f/g$ is expanded in Laurent series as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f/g(z) = \frac{c_{-1}}{z-a} + c_0 + c_1 (z-a)+ \ldots
\end{eqnarray*}

with $c_{-1} \ne 0$.

It follows that the function $f/g (z) -\frac{c_{-1}}{z-a}$ has a removable singularity at $a$. Therefore we have the equality on $B(0, r')\backslash \{a\}$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
f/g(z) = \frac{c_{-1}}{z-a}  + h(z)
\end{eqnarray}
where $B(0,r') \supset \bar B(0,r)$ and $h$ is a holomorphic function on $B(0,r')$. 
Consider the power series expansion at $z=0$ for  both of the terms in the sum

Denote $c= c_{-1}$. We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{c}{z-a}= -\frac{c}{a}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{a}} = -\frac{c}{a} \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{1}{a^n} \cdot z^n = \sum_{n\ge 0} (-\frac{c}{a^{n+1}})z^n 
\end{eqnarray*}
for $|z| < |a|$.

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
h(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} b_n z^n
\end{eqnarray*}
for $|z|< r'$. Since $r' >r$ the series is convergent when $|z|=r$. It follows that $b_n a^n \to 0$

The function $f/g(z)$ has the series expansion at $z=0$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f/g(z) = \sum a_n z^n
\end{eqnarray*}
where 
$$a_n = -\frac{c}{a^{n+1}} + b_n$$
We have 
$$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{ -\frac{c}{a^{n+1}} + b_n } { -\frac{c}{a^{n+2}} + b_{n+1} } = \\
=\frac{ - a c +   b_n a^{n+2}} {\ \ \  -c +  b_{n+1}a^{n+2} }\to a
$$

Main idea: $\frac{c}{z-a}$ determines the asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of the expansion of $f/g(z)$ at $0$.

Comment: If this is a hint, what is a solution? :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: was trying to convince myself   :-)

Comment: The book hasn't presented Laurent series so far. This is actually after showing every holomorphic function over a domain $D$ admits a powerseries development around each point of $D$. I was thinking about using that the $a_n$ are given by an integral and juggling with that, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The function $h\colon = f/g$ is the sum of a multiple of $\frac{1}{1- z/a} $ and a holomorphic function on a larger ball $B(0,r')$. I think this is the key. If you want to avoid  Laurent series multiply by $(z-a)$.

Comment: Oh, OK, you can represent the coefficients by an integral. It will be on a contour formed by a small disk around $a$ and the boundary of $B(0,r')$ and . You will still get the decomposition $h = \text{first integral}+ \text{second integral}$. The first integral is still $\frac{c}{1-z/a}$, the second a holomorphic function on $B(0,r')$.